# Mysql split_str function is returning empty value if delimiter is not exists in the column value

Tags: mysql

I am using following user defined mysql function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');


`select split_str(‘1||john’,'||’,2);` - result "john".
```

But this function is not working if the column value is not having delimiter string(||)

```
select split_str(‘john’,'||’,2); - required result john.
```

But I am getting empty value. Please give any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN case when CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) = CHAR_LENGTH(x) then x else (REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '')) end;
```

you can check it here.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aab54/2

Comment: just try this? what you learn him? what error he made? little explanation to be good answer .

Comment: @echo_Me , code is self explaining. Everyone does not need to be taught in bit by bit